# Convert Text(Date in ISO 8601 format) to DateTime - Data Studio

Tags: datetime, converters, looker-studio, iso8601

I need to convert a text that is in ISO 8601 Date format, to DateTime in DataStudio. When the text comes with the hour and timezone parts having non-zero values, it works normally.
[image]

Code to convert: `DATETIME_ADD(PARSE_DATETIME("%FT%R:%E3S",LEFT_TEXT(CreatedOn,23)), INTERVAL 11-CAST(SUBSTR(CreatedOn,24,3) as INT64) HOUR)`

But when the hour and timezone parts come as zero, the conversion becomes null:
[image]

Code to convert: `DATETIME_ADD(PARSE_DATETIME("%FT%R:%E3S",LEFT_TEXT(BGInvoiceDate,23)), INTERVAL 11-CAST(SUBSTR(BGInvoiceDate,24,3) as INT64) HOUR)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%FT%X",LEFT_TEXT(BGInvoiceDate,19))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rckinfreakshow, "One more question, how do I only keep the date without the time?

Comment: well you can just set the `Type` of this calculated field to just `Date`